# Unable to Obtain Steam Private Data of Myself with my own Apikey and Steamid

Tags: javascript, json, steam, steam-web-api

The URL Im using is

```
http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=12345DA4123456ED05A9A9B41234567&steamids=123123123123123
```

I changed the apikey and steamid because I dont want to share it. The Apikey Is mine and the steamid is someone on my friends list.

The JSON response that I get from that url

```
{
"response": {
    "players": [
        {
            "steamid": "123123123123",
            "communityvisibilitystate": 3,
            "profilestate": 1,
            "personaname": "#",
            "lastlogoff": 123,
            "commentpermission": 2,
            "profileurl": "",
            "avatar": "",
            "avatarmedium": "",
            "avatarfull": "",
            "personastate": 0,
            "primaryclanid": "123123123",
            "timecreated": 123123123,
            "personastateflags": 0
        }
    ]

}
```

}

Comment: Where's the problem? That looks like your info.

Comment: Changed, you were right but I meant a friend's steam id and private data not mine.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Steam API but I'm pretty sure they won't allow you access to the private data of another user, even if they are in your friends list. Public data, sure.

Comment: K Thanks kinda sucks but I think I can find a solution